# 12.04 monitor brightness commands ignored

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, brightness

I cannot change the brightness of the monitor on a laptop either from the command line or from keyboard shortcuts.  I have verified that the file in /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness is changing.  I have also verified that I am running the nvidia drivers.

Things I have tried:

1. Adding entries to /etc/default/grub The `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` entries now read

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quite nosplash acpi_backlight=vendor"
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="noapic"
   ```

   I have also tried various commands here (with an update grub and reboot each time) but nothing has helped
2. I enabled brightness control in /etc/X11/xorg.conf so that it now looks like

   ```
   Section "Device"
           Identifier "Default Device"
           Driver "nvidia"
           Option "NoLogo" "True"
           Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
   EndSection
   ```
3. Investigated installing `linux-kamal-mjgbacklight` and determined it was not applicable to my system

Nothing seems to have made any difference.  I am using an Nvidia GeForce GT 330M with driver version 295.40.  Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you add the model # of the laptop?

Answer (score 1):

Did you enable additional drivers?
If so, disable it, and it works!

You don't need the additional drivers to enable desktop effects and stuff, by installing `ccsm` you can do all that.